# Having trouble with Character.isWhiteSpace() in Java

Tags: java, character

I have this one problem for homework that I need to solve. The code is working fine, except for the white space option. NetBeans gives me a warning when I use .isWhiteSpace, but it goes away when I use .isWhitespace. Either way, when I run the program and enter a space or a tab, the program just keeps running, completely ignoring it. Any suggestions?

```
package problemset3;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProblemSet3
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
      String userString = in.next();
      char userChar = userString.charAt(0);


        if (Character.isDigit(userChar))
        {
          System.out.println("Character is a number.");    
        }
        else if (Character.isLetter(userChar))
        {
         if (Character.isUpperCase(userChar))
         {
             System.out.println("Character is an upper case letter");
         }
         else
         {
             System.out.println("Character is a lower case letter");
         }
        }
        else if (Character.isWhitespace(userChar))
        {
            System.out.println("Character is white space.");
        }
        else
        {
          System.out.println("Character is unknown");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "NetBeans gives me a warning" - what warning, where? Are you sure it's a warning rather than an error? (It looks like it should be an error, because `isWhiteSpace` isn't a method in `Character`, whereas `isWhitespace` is.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your use of [`Scanner.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--):

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern.

The default delimiter for `Scanner` is whitespace - so it isn't going to return whitespace.

You might want to use `nextLine` instead... but be aware that if the user just presses return, the line will be empty, so `charAt(0)` will throw an exception.